# Make Haskell Imperative

Tags: haskell, state-monad, imperative

Note: this is an exercise, and I'm trying to understand how things work.

I am trying to make it possible to do something like this in Haskell:

```
f :: Integer -> Integer
f n = def $ do
  i      <- var n
  while i (>0) $ do
    i      -= lit 1
  return i
-- for now, my program returns n
```

Below is my program. At this point, I cannot understand why it doesn't work, but for some reason, the variables are not changing.

```
import Control.Monad.State


data Lit a = Lit a
type Variable a = State Integer a


def :: Variable (Lit a) -> a
def (State f) = fromLit . fst . f $ 0 

fromLit :: Lit a -> a
fromLit (Lit a) = a

lit :: a -> Lit a
lit l = Lit l

var :: a -> Variable (Lit a)
var v = State $ \x -> (lit v, x)

while :: Lit a -> (a -> Bool) -> Variable () -> Variable ()
while (Lit r) cond act = do
                 if cond r then do
                          _ <- act
                          while (Lit r) cond act
                    -- or act >> while (Lit r) cond act
                 else return ()


op :: (Integer -> Integer -> Integer) -> Lit Integer -> Lit Integer -> Variable ()
op f (Lit a) (Lit b) = State $ \n -> ((), if n == a then f a b else n)
-- that is, if the state is (a) change it to (f a b), else don't change it

(+=) = op (+)
(-=) = op (-)
(*=) = op (*)
```

Please, help me to understand what is wrong here and how to improve the code. Thank you.

Comment: I disagree with the downvotes, and I think this is a nice exercise on how to model imperative constructs (well, at long as you don't then use this style for everyday code :-)). Anyway, `State Integer` is not an appropriate monad for this unless your imperative programs will use only a single variable. You probably need `State (VariableName -> Integer)`, or the `Map` analogous for more efficiency. For top efficiency, I'd use `ST s` instead.

Comment: @chi, what is `VariableName` here?

Comment: It can be `String`, or whatever type you want to use for variable names. One can also use `Int`, in principle. If you want, there can be called "locations" or "references" instead, since you seem to create them with `var`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It goes without saying that this is a silly thing to do in Haskell; but I'm all for trying silly things if it helps you learn something.

I think you should probably back off to a simpler problem and experiment with the State monad a bit more before trying something complex like this; from the code snippets you posted I suspect your intuition is a bit off.

You CAN do this sort of thing of course, but it's tricky to handle variables of "arbitrary" type in a State monad (which must have a fixed type for the state). You can do it in a relatively type-safe way using `Dynamic` and `Proxy`; but I think that might still be a bit out of reach.

We'll start by storing variables of just type Int. I'm not sure which `State` monad you're using, but I'll use the one from `mtl` instead.

```
import Control.Monad.State
import qualified Data.Map as M
import Data.Maybe

data Var = Var Int
  deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

data Env = Env {freshVar :: Int, vars :: M.Map Var Int}
  deriving Show

type Imperative a = State Env a
```

I've defined the `Env` type which keeps track of all the variables we've "created", as well as a "fresh name" generator, which is just an Int that keeps counting upwards as we define variables.

```
lit :: Int -> Imperative Var
lit n = do
    varID <- gets freshVar
    let newVar = Var varID
    modify (\s -> s{freshVar=n+1, vars=(M.insert newVar n (vars s))})
    return newVar
```

This code creates a new "variable" from a literal number, it does so by getting a fresh variable name from the environment, wrapping it in a constructor, then storing it in the environment with the provided value. Note that we bump the freshVar number so we'll get a different variable id for the next literal.

```
getVar :: Var -> Imperative Int
getVar v = gets (fromJust . M.lookup v . vars)

setVar :: Var -> Int -> Imperative ()
setVar v n = modify (\s -> s{vars=M.insert v n (vars s)})
```

These are some helpers which look up variable or set variables in our Map of variables. `getVar` uses `fromJust` which is unsafe in general; but if you only define new variables with "lit" then it works fine.

```
op :: (Int -> Int -> Int) -> Var -> Var -> Imperative ()
op f aVar bVar = do
    a <- getVar aVar
    b <- getVar bVar
    setVar aVar (f a b)

(+=) = op (+)
(-=) = op (-)
(*=) = op (*)
```

To perform your version of a mutation operation we take two variables, look up their current values, perform the operation, then store the result into the variable on the left.

Now we can define `while`

```
while :: Imperative Bool -> Imperative () -> Imperative ()
while cond act = do
    continue <- cond
    if continue then act >> while cond act
                else return ()
```

We can accept any imperative statement which returns a boolean as the condition; the user can look up the state of variables within the statement if they need to. We simply run the statement, if we want to continue we `act` and then recurse, otherwise we return.

```
f :: Int -> Int
f n = run $ do
  i <- lit n
  while ((>0) <$> getVar i) $ do
    one <- lit 1
    i -= one
  getVar i
```

It's a bit wordy (we could simplify it down, but it would make the combinators more complex). We define our `i` as a new variable with the value `n`, then check whether it's greater than `0` in the condition. In the loop body we define a variable with the value `1`, then subtract it from the variable `i`.

After the loop terminates we check the value of `i`

```
run :: Imperative a -> a
run m = evalState m (Env 0 M.empty)
```

Here's the `run` function we used above, which simply runs state with no variables defined.

If you try it out you'll see it successfully hits zero; and you can add a trace statement to see which values it hits:

```
import Debug.Trace
f :: Int -> Int
f n = run $ do
  i <- lit n
  while ((>0) <$> getVar i) $ do
    getVar i >>= traceShowM
    one <- lit 1
    i -= one
  getVar i

>>> f 10
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0
```